# How to disable submit button with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox which needs to be checked in order for it to be possible to submit the form.

So I set the submit button disabled attribute to "disabled". Then I tried binding the checkbox to it like this so it would enable/disable the submit button. It does not work:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]#confirm').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#submitButton').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#submitButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

The submit button stays disabled.

HTML:

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" action="/controller/action"><dl class="zend_form">
<dd id="confirm-element">
<input type="hidden" name="confirm" value="0"><input type="checkbox" name="confirm" id="confirm" value="1" class="input-checkbox"></dd>
<dt id="confirm-label"><label for="confirm" class="required">Lorem ipsum.</label></dt>
<dt id="submitButton-label">&#160;</dt><dd id="submitButton-element">
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="Potvrdiť" class="input-submit" disabled="disabled"></dd>

<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="ed3e9347145a3eb3d58c4c21d813df26" id=""></dl></form>
```

Comment: Setting the submit button to disabled might not be enough. Consider preventing the default submit event of the form (in some browsers pressing enter in a simple input text box also submits the form).

Comment: @bazmegakapa That's not needed. I have that secured at the server side if someone tries to go around the javascript. I just need to make it visually visible that the form can only be submitted after the checkbox input has been checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$('#confirm').change(function() {
   $('#submitButton').attr('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

according to comments below, now this should fixed your problem.

```
$('#confirm').change(function() {
   $('#submitButton').button( "option", "disabled", !this.checked );
});
```

Comment: hmmm I made a type there. and lonesomeday already fixed it. it should work... [here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/TBHyw/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#submitButton").attr("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the button, but you still have a click on the button so you have to [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the click event from the button:

```
$("#submitButton").attr('disabled', 'disabled').unbind('click');
```

Comment: That's not my problem. My issue is that the submit button stays disabled.

Comment: You cannot click on a disabled button anyways.

Comment: if tested your script, and it runs aswel.. but you want a normal form post? try to post form with .submit() on the click event from the button

Comment: Ehm. Read my question. I want to disable/enable the submti button with the checkbox. That's means setting/unsetting its disabled attribute.

Comment: like i said, i tested you script you posted. it works fine..

i tested this: http://pastie.org/1455449